# Delaying member function instantiation in crtp base class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Currently, I have a CRTP base class which utilizes a traits class to determine the return type of it's member functions.  I've been playing around with C++11 and have the following code which eliminates the need for the traits class, but requires default function template parameters.  Is there some way to modify this to work in visual studio 2012 which doesn't support that feature of C++11?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Ignore> 
struct ignore { typedef T type; };

template<typename T> 
struct A 
{
    template<class IgnoredParam = void>
    auto foo() -> decltype(declval<typename ignore<T*, IgnoredParam>::type >()->foo_impl()) 
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }        
};

struct B : public A<B> 
{
    int foo_impl() { return 0;}

};

int main()
{
    B b;
    int i = b.foo();
    cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Does it support variadic template parameters?

Comment: @litb : No, it doesn't support variadic templates either.  here is a [list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) of the features it supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
decltype(declval<T>()->foo_impl())
```

as the deferred return type.

Comment: When I try that I get an error about the invalid use of the incomplete type B.  I had changed the declaration to `auto foo() -> decltype(declval<T*>()->foo_impl())`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Joe : Which version of VC11 are you using? AFAIK what you're seeing is a bug and was fixed after the Developer Preview.

Comment: @ildjam : I'm receiving the error using the RC.  I also tried gcc 4.7 and received the same error.  I think the error is correct because the compiler tries to instantiate foo when B is still an incomplete type.  That's what I was trying to get around with ignore and the function template parameter in my original post which delayed the instantiation until foo was actually called and, at that point, B was a complete type.

Comment: No he cannot use that because the function is declared as soon as the class is instantiated. But `T` is an incomplete type when that base class is instantiated so that will result in an error.